# Running php bin/magento setup:upgrade command gives error

Tags: php, magento

I have created Simple Module in Magento 2.4.1. After creating a module I have tried to run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command but it gives error of **SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'furniturestore.catalog_product_index_eav' doesn't exist in engine, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` WHERE `Non_unique` = 1**. I have also tried for running **php bin/magento indexer:reindex** but it gives error of **Product EAV index exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of '.\furniturestore\catalog_product_index_eav' to '.\furniturestore\catalog_product_index_eav_outdated'(errno: 155 "The table does not exist in the storage engine"), query was: RENAME TABLE catalog_product_index_eav TO catalog_product_index_eav_outdated,catalog_product_index_eav_replica TO catalog_product_index_eav,catalog_product_index_eav_outdated TO catalog_product_index_eav_replica**.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue, you need to create a flat table catalog_category_flat_store_1.

- Disable magento Catalog Flat for Category from Admin>Store>Catalog>Catalog>Use Flat Catalog Category. Make it 'NO'.
- Then Flush magento Cache by `php bin/magento cache:flush`
- Then you should drop the table catalog_category_flat_store_1, if it is exists in the db, by drop table catalog_category_flat_store_1.
- Next enable Catalog Flat for Category by Use Flat Catalog Category. Make it 'yes'.
- Finally, you need to index from magento cli : `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`.

Answer (score 0):

TO resolve this issue, you need to create a flat table catalog_product_index_eav.
For more info see [create table](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html)